# How to redirect from a plain Java class to a JSP?

Tags: java

How to redirect from a plain JAVA class to JSP? The control for this class is coming from DWR AJAx.

Answer (score 1):

If this JSP is in the same Web Container then you can use **[RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)**.

To obtain **RequestDispatcher** you can use, one of:

- **ServletContext**.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)
- **ServletContext**.getNamedDispatcher(java.lang.String)
- **ServletRequest**.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)

Comment: I tried HttpServletRequest request = ExecutionContext.get().getHttpServletRequest();
       HttpServletResponse response = ExecutionContext.get().getHttpServletResponse();RequestDispatcher path = request.getRequestDispatcher("Error.jsp");
           path.forward(request,response); However, its throwing JSP Processing Error, saying filenot found

Comment: Maybe you should try to use "/Error.jsp" instead of "Error.jsp".

Comment: You must provide more information, about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but if you want to use a template library from plain Java code, maybe you should not use JSP, but FreeMarker. That would lower your coupling with the Servlet API.

Take a look at this:

http://freemarker.org/

Comment: How do you infer that the OP wants / needs a template library rather than a JSP?  He >>asked<< about a JSP.

Comment: I don't infer anything. Just don't think it's a good idea to couple a plain Java class to the Servlet/JSP API. Don't you?

Comment: Well obviously, the "plain Java class" has to be a Servlet class if it is *handling* a request (... unless the OP has implemented the HTTP server-side stack for himself).  So he must be talking about redirecting from a "plain" Servlet request handler method to a JSP.

Comment: He's using DWR, which can invoke really plain Java clases.

Comment: From a JSP1, On click of sort button, Im calling a JS(DWR) which inturn invokes Simple JAVA class(where the sorting logic is done) and displays the records in the grid(which is there in JSP1). Now On Null check, I want that to redirect to some other JSP(say Error.jsp)

Comment: On that case, the redirection should be done by the DWR code, not by the plain Java class.

Comment: Andres, Can you please provide a sample logic on how to implement that in the DWR, Since I'm very new to this.